# Test equality of two functions in python

Tags: python, function, metaprogramming, equality

I want to make two functions equal to each other, like this:

```
def fn_maker(fn_signature):
  def _fn():
    pass
  _fn.signature = fn_signature
  return _fn

# test equality of two function instances based on the equality of their signature values
>>> fa = fn_maker(1)
>>> fb = fn_maker(1)
>>> fc = fn_maker(2)
>>> fa == fb # should be True, same signature values
True
>>> fa == fc # should be False, different signature values
False
```

How should I do it? I know I could probably override `eq` and `ne` if fa, fb, fc are instances of some class. But here **eq** is not in dir(fa) and adding it the list doesnt work. 
I figured out some workaround like using a cache, e.g.,

```
def fn_maker(fn_signature):
  if fn_signature in fn_maker.cache:
    return fn_maker.cache[fn_signature]
  def _fn():
    pass
  _fn.signature = fn_signature
  fn_maker.cache[fn_signature] = _fn
  return _fn
fn_maker.cache = {}
```

By this way there is a guarantee that there is only one function for the same signature value (kinda like a singleton). But I am really looking for some neater solutions.

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve. There might be an easier approach.

Comment: Yes, @ms4py, thank you for pointing that out. There could be easier solutions to the problem I am working on, like using a class instead of a function. But the thing that I really want to learn is how to 'override' == behavior for functions in python, or it is simply impossible.

Comment: No, I think there should be a more general solution than comparing functions, no matter how you do it technically. Can you describe why you want to compare them?

Comment: And you cannot override `__eq__` for functions, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to override the `__eq__` implementation for functions (tested with Python 2.7)

```
>>> def f():
...   pass
...
>>> class A(object):
...   pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a == f
False
>>> setattr(A, '__eq__', lambda x,y: True)
>>> a == f
True
>>> setattr(f.__class__, '__eq__', lambda x,y: True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'function'
```

Answer (score 6):

If you turned your functions into instances of some class that overrides `__call__()` as well as the comparison operators, it will be very easy to achieve the semantics you want.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip. But I want to know how far I can really go without wrapping it within an object, like what we can do with functions in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible.

But overriding `__call__` seems a nice solution to me.